# Pass to my form WCF client message

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have `Winforms` application that host `WCF` service.
this is my `Button connect event`:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            // Returns a list of ipaddress configuration
            IPHostEntry ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            // Get machine ipaddress

            IPAddress _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(tbServerIp.Text);

            // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be started
            urlService = "net.tcp://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8000/MyService";

            // Instruct the ServiceHost that the type that is used is a ServiceLibrary.service1
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));
            host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
            host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
            host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
            host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);

            // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // <- Very crucial

            // Add a endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceLibrary.IService1), tcpBinding, urlService);

            // A channel to describe the service. Used with the proxy scvutil.exe tool
            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
            metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (metadataBehavior == null)
            {
                // This is how I create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
                metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8001/MyService");
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                metadataBehavior.ToString();
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                urlMeta = metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl.ToString();
                //pbIndicator.Image = Resources.indicator_green;
                btnConnect.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btnConnect.Text = "Stop";
            }

            host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

And this is my ServiceLibrary:

```
namespace ServiceLibrary
{
    public delegate void StatusEventHandler(string srt);

    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string MyOperation1(string myValue);
        [OperationContract]
        string MyOperation2(DataContract1 dataContractValue);
        [OperationContract]
        string HelloWorld(string str);
    }

    public class service1 : IService1
    {
        public event StatusEventHandler StartEvent;

        public string MyOperation1(string myValue)
        {
            return "Hello: " + myValue;
        }
        public string MyOperation2(DataContract1 dataContractValue)
        {
            return "Hello: " + dataContractValue.FirstName;
        }
        public string HelloWorld(string str)
        {
            StartEvent(str);
            //return "Helloworld from " + str;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DataContract1
    {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to do is to pass the client message from `HelloWorld function` to my main form, so i try to create event inside `class service1`:

```
public delegate void StatusEventHandler(string srt);
public event StatusEventHandler StartEvent;
```

but it remained null even after registered from my main form (inside my button click event)
What is the simplest way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created a service host, you gave a type, which means that with every call to your service, a new instance of that type will be created.

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));
```

You need to pass an instance of your service to the servicehost constructor, so every call will use that instance.

```
var yourServiceInstance = new ServiceLibrary.service1();

// attach event handlers here

host = new ServiceHost(yourServiceInstance);
```

When you do this, your service class needs to be configured for single instance mode:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class service1
{
   // methods here
}
```

Comment: I need to replace yourServiceInstance  with something else ? because in this way i cannot connest: (In order to use one of the ServiceHost constructors that takes a service instance, the InstanceContextMode of the service must be set to InstanceContextMode.Single.  This can be configured via the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.  Otherwise, please consider using the ServiceHost constructors that take a Type argument.)

Comment: If you don't have an instance of your service class yet, you will need to create a new one. Probably a class field.

Comment: Well, that message includes a solution to your problem. "The InstanceContextMode of the service must be set to InstanceContextMode.Single". Do so and it will work.

Comment: Can i have an example (i am a new developer...) ?

Comment: InstanceContextMode.Single has effect of how many clients can connect to my service ?